# tabstat: How to sort/order the output by a certain variable?

Tags: stata

I gathered some NBA players' data of their triple-double games, and would like to find out who got the most explosive data on average.

The source is "Basketball Reference - Player Game Finder - Triple Doubles".(Sorry that I can't post the direct url because of the lack of reputation)

So I generated a table summarizing  descriptive statistics (e.g. count mean) for several variables (`pts trb ast stl blk`) using：

`tabstat pts trb ast stl blk, statistics(count mean) format(%9.1f) by(player)`

What I get is the following table:

`tabstat` result:

[image]

How can I tell Stata to filter the players by `count >= 10` (who got 10 or more triple-doubles ever)  as a column then sort the table by `pts` and get:

Ideal result:

[image]

Like above, I would say Michael Jordan and James Harden are the Top 2 most explosive triple-double players and Darrell Walker is the most economic one.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to create a variable defining the order desired in advance of your `tabstat` call. To get it (value) labelled as you wish, use `labmask` (`search labmask` then download from the *Stata Journal* location given).

Here is some technique.

```
sysuse auto, clear 

egen mean = mean(weight), by(rep78) 
egen count = count(weight), by(rep78) 

egen group = group(mean rep78) if count >= 5 
replace group = -group 
labmask group, values(rep78) 
label var group "`: var label rep78'" 

tabstat mpg weight , by(group) s(count mean) format(%1.0f) 

Summary statistics: N, mean
  by categories of: group (Repair Record 1978)

 group |       mpg    weight
-------+--------------------
     2 |         8         8
       |        19      3354
-------+--------------------
     3 |        30        30
       |        19      3299
-------+--------------------
     4 |        18        18
       |        22      2870
-------+--------------------
     5 |        11        11
       |        27      2323
-------+--------------------
 Total |        67        67
       |        21      3030
----------------------------
```

Key details:

1. The grouping variable is based not only on the means you want to sort on but also on the original grouping variable, just in case there are ties on the means.
2. To get ordering from highest mean downwards, the grouping variable must be negated.
3. `tabstat` doesn't show variable labels in the body of the table. (Usually there wouldn't be enough space for them.)